# How to make focus stable for custom text field material-ui-pickers?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

When I passed custom text field to date picker then focus loses after each keyboard input. How to fix that?

Sandbox example https://codesandbox.io/embed/datepicker-y0dn7

````
  <DatePicker
     keyboard
     label="Masked input"
     format="DD.MM.YYYY"
     mask={value =>
       value
         ? [/\d/, /\d/, ".", /\d/, /\d/, ".", /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/]
         : []
     }
     value={selectedDate ? moment(selectedDate) : null}
     onChange={date => {
       handleDateChange(date);
       setFormattedValue(date.format("DD.MM.YYYY"));
     }}
     error={!!errorText}
     helperText={errorText}
     TextFieldComponent={props => (
       <TextField
         {...props}
         value={formattedValue}
         onChange={event => setFormattedValue(event.target.value)}
       />
     )}
   />```
````

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `TextField` `onChange` function. If you remove this attribute, you will see it stops losing focus. Maybe it is because `TextFieldComponent` function is rendered every time you digit and follow the [documentation](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/api/DatePicker), `Override input component`, that makes it loses focus because recreate the input every time.

Comment: I've used onInputChange property instead of onChange property for custom text field and focus still loses after keyboard input https://codesandbox.io/embed/datepicker-2-u79qu

Comment: I know maybe you can't change, but I would use the latest version of material-ui-picker. You may check it out here: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-datepicker-jzogw

Comment: It works without custom TextFieldComponent, but I'm trying to sort it out with custom TextFieldComponent

Answer (score 0):

For the way you're using the picker, you could have probably got away with just providing the `format` option like you did, but skip providing the TextField entirely (unless of course you're doing more with the TextField in your actual code).

That being said, I had seen something that suggested splitting the TextField component out into a functional component to get this to keep focus which seems to work in my case.

https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-joliot-ug1kr